# Error: Packages not found - Xamarin Android - Mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, xamarin.android

Everytime I try to deploy the app to an emulator I get this errors. Reading some posts I think it could be that Xamarin isn't recognizing the Android support libraries but I don't know how to fix it in Mac. When I develop in Visual Studio in Windows I don't have any problem, but when I develop in Xamarin Studio in Mac this happens. Any idea why it happens? How can I resolve it in Mac? I'm a beginner with Mac OS.
Thank you!

[See the error in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1P9z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Uninstalled Android Support Library and reinstalled it from SDK Manager